# how can background video responsive possible?

Tags: html, css, background, html5-video

I am trying but couldn't. Is there any one to help for solution of these problem.

video can be responsible but I need responsive as background.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Did you at least try Google? Search for responsive video background and you get a lot of examples.